# How to apply array formula to join all the cells in a column and exclude empty cells in google sheets doc spreadsheet

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-query-language

`=ArrayFormula(join(",",char(34)&E3:E11&char(34)))` This is the formula I have thus far.

It is able to output the values from the ranges I have manually chosen E3 to E11 which are
Nurse
Nurse Practitioner
Physician Assistant
Dialysis
Nurse Anesthetist
Dental Hygienist
Lab Technician
Diagnostic Technician
Medical Records

The formula is able to output them like this:
`"Nurse","Nurse Practitioner","Physician Assistant","Dialysis","Nurse Anesthetist","Dental Hygienist","Lab Technician","Diagnostic Technician","Medical Records"`

I would like to be able to make the range E3:E so that new values will be automatically outputted when they are added in. But, doing this with the formula I have now just includes a bunch of trailing empty quote values, like this `""` because of the blank cells.

How can I exclude blank cells from applying to my ArrayFormula?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(JOIN(",",CHAR(34)&FILTER(E3:E,E3:E<>"")&CHAR(34)))
```

- 

[image]